# Routine for authentication to clear local data

Tags: android

In android mobiles there is possibility for clearing local data stored without any authentication.If we go to application manager and select an app->click clear data button the local data including files,database will get erased.I have an idea of introducing a routine to authenticate to clear the local data.So that other than user no one can clear it.Is it possible ?

Comment: you want to clear the data in mobile or in db

Comment: clear data in mobile.

Comment: http://www.androidcentral.com/android-201-how-and-when-clear-app-cache-or-data

Comment: actually my point is when i'm using your phone and clearing all your local data your application will be like a newly installed one.So instead when you add an authentication the local data is safe right.

Answer (score 0):

This "CLEAR DATA" option is severely broken for the use-case of Home Screen widgets that may have shared preferences and/or some local cached data.

It is also completely against the developer documentation which says:

"You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer is going to be helpful or not anyway i will tell you my idea,
i don't know if there is any mechanism that prevents the user from clearing the `/data/data/<applicaton folder>` but you can refer the Android device admin API at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html another approach is that(Don't know if that's even possible) to listen to the Settings>apps activity and show an authentication form but i think that wont be able to solve this problem here anyway maybe this idea may ring a bell

Comment: I will quote my example,i am playing temple run in my mobile i gained a lot of points,all the local data such as your points,ur gem collected will be internally stored.when my friend does a clear data on it without my knowledge either it may be game i can lose my data permenently.So i suggest an authentication.